# Cakephp form not posting all field values in POST method

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0 version when I am posting a form that contain 1000 fields(1000 input check boxes) its not submitting all the 1000 fields.Only submitting the 495 field and their values. After posting it displaying the following data(Response) in my controller

```
[data] => Array
    (
        [Ecommerce] => Array
            (
                [r] => no
                [rcompleted] => yes
                [rstart_date] => May 1, 2013  00:00
                [rcompleted_date] => May 31, 2013  00:00

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                    )
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                 [495] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                    )
                )
```

Please note the problem not in localhost only in Live server. I am thinking may be the problem related to **max_input_vars**              but not have idea on this.. any ones help appreciated

Comment: see in the `phpinfo();` for the value that is set for `max_input_vars` I think this will be less than 1000, by default this value is 1000 anyways.

Comment: I checked it first, Its is 1000,, Shall I increase 3000 using ini_set because its a supporting server( not a dedicated/ shared server)

Comment: yes you can try that, you should get more results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can change the following line in `php.ini`:

```
; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
max_input_vars = 1000
```

We can increase this to `3000` and then it will work.